Feature extraction and librosa
I am building speech to text model I loaded the audio files using librosa.load()
I resample it and i normalized it then i use MFCC
The problem is that the number of Features =1000 and the sentences=6000
Note : i compare the name of the audio with the name of the sentence
What should i do Expecting to get the right number of data
here is the code
audio_dir = '/content/cv-corpus-12.0-delta-2022-12-07/en/clips/'
audio_column = df1['path']
    import os
    import librosa
    import numpy as np

Specify the directory where your audio files are located
   audio_dir = '/content/cv-corpus-12.0-delta-2022-12-07/en/clips'

Assuming df1 is your DataFrame containing the paths
   audio_column = df1['path']

Iterate over all files in the directory
       for filename in os.listdir(audio_dir):

    if filename.endswith('.wav') or filename.endswith('.mp3'):
    # Check if the filename (without directory part) exists in the audio_column
    if filename in audio_column.values:
        # Construct the full path to the audio file
        audio_file_path = os.path.join(audio_dir, filename)

        # Load the audio file using librosa
        audio_data, sample_rate = librosa.load(audio_file_path, sr=None,mono=True, dtype=np.float32)

        # Print some information about the resampled audio file
        print(f'Resampled {filename} to {sample_rate} Hz:')
    else:
        continue
     resampled_audio=librosa.resample(audio_data,orig_sr=sample_rate,target_sr=16000)

     normalized_audio_signal = librosa.util.normalize(resampled_audio)
   stft=librosa.core.stft(normalized_audio_signal,n_fft=2048,hop_length=512)

s=np.abs(stft)
a=librosa.amplitude_to_db(s)
librosa.display.specshow(a)

mfccs=librosa.feature.mfcc(y=t,sr=16000,n_mfcc=13)


I do not understand the problem. Can you rephrase it?
